# AHCI Base Address

Tags: assembly, memory-address

How can I get the AHCI Base Address (ABAR) ? How can I get to know, which memory address is this? I know, it counts from the PCI base address, but I don't know how can I get the PCI base address, too.

Answer (score 0):

AHCI base address is located in the BAR5 of AHCI host controller, which is also a PCI device. The "BAR5" here indicates the offset 0x27~0x24(DWORD) in the PCI configuration space. To get this base address s/w should issue the configuration read cycle !

Below is the code example to get BAR5 using assembly language(assume AHCI host controller is in Bus 3,Device 0, function 0)

```
mov eax, 80030024h  ; PCI function address
mov dx, 0cf8h       ; config address io port
out dx, eax
mov dx, 0cfch       ; get data from config data port
in eax, dx          ; read DWORD into register eax
```

Maybe the first thing you should do is to study the PCI specification. And then you can check below links:

[PCI configuration space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space),
[Access registers in a PCI config space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778121/proper-way-to-access-registers-in-a-pci-configuration-space)

Answer (score 0):

I am tring to read memory from AHCI base address recently.
I just found three methods which can help.
Method 1 . you may read pci base address by winring0.There are so many demos you can download. The link is  The link is http://bbs.aau.cn/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=4914.
Method 2.I just run the third tool(lspci.exe) to read the ahci base address.

```
 private string getAhciBaseAddress()
    {
        string output = "";      

        ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\pciutils-3.2.0\lspci.exe";
        StartInfo.Arguments = "-v -s.2";    
        StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;//不重定向输入      
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //重定向输出 
        StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //不创建窗口 
        StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        Process myProcess = null;
        try
        {
            myProcess = Process.Start(StartInfo);
            while (!myProcess.HasExited)
            {
                myProcess.WaitForExit(3000);
            }
            output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();//读取进程的输出 
            Console.WriteLine("output==" + output);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myProcess != null)  myProcess.Close();    

        }
        string key = "Memory at ";
        int index = output.IndexOf(key);
        string addressString = "";
        int length = IntPtr.Size == 4 ? 8 : 16;
        if (index!= -1)
        {
            addressString = output.Substring(index + +key.Length, length);
        }
        return addressString;
    }
```

The link is http://blog.csdn.net/shmily453397/article/details/13767599